# IF EXISTS in WHERE clause?

Tags: sql-server-2008, sql-server-2008-r2

I want to insert a condition in one of my queries, but don't really know how to do it.
Basically, I'm sorting a bunch of files by their folder _id, i.e. the folder they belong to (using order by folder_id). What I'd like now, for each of these groups of files, is the query to pick the first file that satisfies a particular condition. If that condition is not satisfied by any of the files in a folder, than the query should pick the first document available in the folder.

This is my query (simplified):

```
select folder_id,
       file_id,
       first_name
from f_file
where first_name = 'John'
order by folder_id
```

So, if my results now are:

```
FOLDER ID    FILE ID      AUTHOR
A            32           John
A            41           John
A            56           Thomas
A            78           Peter
B            02           Peter
B            03           Peter
B            45           Peter
C            34           John
C            56           Thomas
C            77           Peter
C            86           John
D            12           Peter
D            34           Thomas
D            89           Thomas
```

for each folder, I'd like the query to show only the first document (lowest file_id) that was created by John. If there are no documents created by John at all in that folder, than the first one from any other author will do.

```
FOLDER ID    FILE ID      AUTHOR
A            32           John
B            02           Peter
C            34           John
D            12           Peter
```

So, the ID has to be the lowest, but the Author has to be John or another one.
My idea would be to insert an `IF EXISTS` clause in the `WHERE` clause, but how to do it?

Thanks for your responses.
Val

Comment: You should show an example in your sample data and desired results where John just didn't conveniently happen to also have the lowest file_id.

Comment: For folders B and D John doesn't have the lowest file_id, so the first docs from Peter are showing.

Comment: I think you missed my point. For B and D John doesn't have a file at all. Do you see how one potential use case (and arguably the most important one) is missing? Add John to one of those sets, with a higher file_id. Your sample data needs to show how we actually solve the problem. It's like asking for code that deals, with leap years but only has sample data for April 2007.